# Changing white-space wrap options for small/xs screen size in WP

Tags: wordpress, css, whitespace, responsive

I am editing a WP page that was created by someone else, and I'm very new to this kind of thing.

There are two buttons on the page. I want to change the white-space: nowrap; to white-space: normal - but only on the small/xs screen sizes.
I created a rule in css just for this, but when I reduce my screen size to 1195pxls, the button text already starts to wrap much too early. I don't want that to happen until around 320pxls.

I don't know WP well, but it limits the code I can directly edit and in the css I can't find any of the bootstrap code - including the .btn class - only custom code bits created by the previous creator of the page.

Is there a way that I can target the specific buttons in question right in the html with a style element or something?

B.

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried? And did you put the code into a `@media-query` with that screen-size rule?

Comment: Hi! Well, guess what? it was a simple case of changing the div's width, which was set to 33.33333%. I changed it to auto and the button does what I want it to do :) Thanks so much for your reply, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well good on ya and happy coding!